# Authentication user moves in game server when user is logged in on web server

Tags: authentication, architecture, authorization

I'm developing game server and i need store some infos in database. I have general feelings how should i do that. The main assumption is that in the future, i will need few game servers and i would like to have well prepared architecture for it. I am asking you guys becouse i think my plan has some "black spots". Here is how I imagine it should work:
[image]

My "black spot" is that when I connect my game server i will have to compare generated token each time player will do something and to do that I will need get it from DB(each time). I could theoretically 'download' correct token from DB on player connected event and then compare token with memory stored token. Is it good way? Is my imagination of this process is correct? I would like to avoid calling DB (or just limit it maximally)

Or is there better way to achieve what i want to achieve? :)

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own...  There are lots of good Single Sign On (SSO) solutions out there.  If you don't want to use them.  Many of them are open-source... If you really do insist on writing your own, please "leverage" their designs.  It will keep you from shooting yourself in the foot.  There are lots of things that you will want to do to keep users from stealing tokens, or spoofing them.